# who is responsible for managing shared memory space?

Tags: database, operating-system, computer-science

Which part of Memory Management System is responsible for managing shared memory space?
and how can this be achieved using virtual memory ?

Comment: Well,memory management can be achieved using virtual memory using the concepts of `paging` and `segmentation`. And,memory is exchanged between `RAM` and `Disk` for swapping and helping in memory management!You better search on the topics which I mentioned!!!